# Can Asp.net HTTP Compression affect pages in specific sub directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax, compression

I have a web application that want to enable HTTP compression on specific pages in a specific sub directory.How is it possible?

Compression in Asp.net 4 has conflict with Asp.net Ajax(*.axd files) like asp.net 2?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [httpCompression Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690689%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) you can locate config file with this element in:

Machine.config
ApplicationHost.config
Root application Web.config
Application Web.config
**Directory Web.config**

So you should create right web.config and move one to desired **directory**.

**UPDATE**

If you wanna do it yourself to see [ASP.NET GZip Encoding Caveats](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats) - it's good article. I suppose you have to write HttpModule that will decide - need compression or not.

Comment: I don't want compress using IIS.I want compress HTTP using asp.net.